# Add custom Cypress command when using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, cypress

I'm trying to create a new `cypress` command which allows me to post a file using `formData` as `cy.request` doesn't support `formData` yet.

I'm using `request-promise-native` for the `POST` itself.

First, in my `commands.ts` I'm extending the `Cypress.Chainable` `interface` like this:

```
declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable<Subject = any> {
      postFormData(
        url: string, 
        formData: FormData, 
        token: string): Chainable<FullResponse>
    }
  }
}
```

`FullResponse` is the response type definition for `request-promise-native`.

My `postFormData` function looks like this:

```
function postFormData(
  url,
  formData,
  token
): Cypress.Chainable<FullResponse> {  // this is line 52
  const response: FullResponse = await post(url, {
    auth: { bearer: token },
    formData
  })
  return cy.wrap(response) // this is line 58
}
```

Finally, I'm registering the new command:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('postFormData', postFormData)
```

In my `test.ts`, I'm calling the command like this:

```
const response = cy.postFormData(
  url,
  formData,
  accessToken)
expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(202)
```

However, `tsc` gives me these errors:

```
commands.ts:52:4 -  error TS1064: The return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise<T> type.

commands.ts:58:3 - error TS1058: The return type of an async function must either be a valid promise or must not contain a callable 'then' member.
```

`cy.wrap` returns a `Chainable` but not a `Promise`, so how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible solution

```
import { post, FullResponse } from 'request-promise-native'

declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable<Subject = any> {
      postFormData(
        url: string, 
        formData: FormData, 
        token: string): Chainable<FullResponse>
    }
  }
}

function postFormData(url, formData, token): Cypress.Chainable<any> {
  return cy.wrap(
    post(url, {
      auth: { bearer: token },
      formData
    })
  )

Cypress.Commands.add('postFormData', postFormData)
```

The correct usage is:

```
cy.postFormData(
  url,
  formData,
  accessToken)
  .then((response) => {
    expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(202)
  })
```

**Update**

As `request` [is in maintainance mode](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142) and there's an [issue with browsers](https://github.com/request/request/issues/1961) and `formData`, here's a solution using `axios`:

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios'

declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable<Subject = any> {
      postFormData(
        url: string,
        formData: FormData,
        token: string
      ): Chainable<AxiosResponse>
    }
  }
}

function postFormData(url, formData, token): Cypress.Chainable<any> {
  return cy.wrap(
    axios(url, {
      method: 'post',
      url,
      data: formData,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    })
  )
}

Cypress.Commands.add('postFormData', postFormData)
```

Usage:

```
cy.postFormData(
  url,
  formData,
  accessToken)
  .then((response) => {
    expect(response.status).to.equal(202)
  })
```